# Detect IVR question and return response using twilio in android studio

Tags: android, ivr

Currently I am working on Twilio API. I need to call IVR number using twilio. IVR Number ask question. In Twilio using speech recognition i want to detect question and provide answer accordingly.

Something Like Need to activate mobile sim-card :-

=> Call to IVR Number (1900)

Question :- Enter your birth-date(Detect question in TWilio and pass answer)

Answer :- 1 January, 2001 (Answerd by Twilio from the android studio)

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple app for that using [Dasha](https://dasha.ai/).

Sample DSL (DashaScript) code:

```
start node root {
    do {
        #connectSafe("<PHONE_NUMBER>"); //make Dasha call your IVR
    }
    transitions {
        birthdate: goto birthdate on #messageHasIntent("birthdate"); //use conversational AI to understand that IVR says "Enter your birth date"
    }
}

node birthdate {
    do {
        #sayText("1 January, 2001"); //say it using Dasha speech synthesis
    }
}
```

You can connect Dasha to your Twilio account so the calls will be going through your Twilio phone number: https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/tutorials/sip-outbound-calls/.

If you need any help, feel free to join our [dev community](http://community.dasha.ai/) or drop me a line at vlad@dasha.ai.

Cheers